# allocating bot to single channel discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to ensure my bot only responds to commands/messages and responds only in 1 specific channel is this possible I have tried multiple variations to no success. even better if I could define it for any event. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `message.channel` in the `on_message` event and if it matches your criteria, in this case a specific channel, then do `process_commands`.

Below is an example where the `!ping` command will only work when `channel.name` is "general".

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == 'general':
        await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('token')
```